# Perl DBI MySQL Error Msg : Can't call method "do" on an undefined value

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am trying to run simple perl dbi example script to connect to mysql database and do some inserts.

Code:

```
#! bin/usr/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI();
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:mysql:database=SPM;host=IP Address", "username", "password",
    {'RaiseError'=>1}
);

my $dbh->do(
    'INSERT INTO payment_methods(name, description)VALUES(CASH, DOLLAR)'
);
my $dbh->disconnect();
```

But when I try to run this using `perl filename.pl` I get following

`Can't call method "do" on an undefined value at perldbi.pl line 12`

That is where I have used `do` for first time.

I have tried to google it and also to tried all different kinds of forum but in vain, if you have any idea as to why this is happening and what is way around for this than it would be really great and I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Using the -w on the shebang line is redundant if you `use warnings`.  See `perldoc perllexwarn` for more info: http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html

Comment: Plus, more than likely, the shebang line is wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for guiding me on this issue.

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure you pay attention to all warnings ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have an extra `my`:

```
my $dbh->do(
    'INSERT INTO payment_methods(name, description)VALUES(CASH, DOLLAR)'
);
```

Get rid of that `my`.

You either do not really have `warnings` enabled in your script or you are ignoring the warnings:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = 1;
my $x = 2;
```

```
C:\Temp> t
"my" variable $x masks earlier declaration in same scope at ...
```

Comment: Only found it because I was editing the OP's post to avoid horizontal scrolling. My hatred of horizontal scrolling has finally paid off.

Comment: Yet another example of the benefits of using `warnings`!

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it's the reason for the error message, but the values in the insert are probably not right:

```
  VALUES(CASH, DOLLAR)
```

Should probably be:

```
  VALUES(\'CASH\', \'DOLLAR\')
```

The `\` is required because you're using a `'` style string.  If you use a `"` style string instead, you could leave out the `\`:

```
 "... VALUES('CASH','DOLLAR')"
```

Comment: For such things placeholders were developed.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your database connection is failing. So `$dbh` is undefined.</strike>

**Update:** Both comments are right.  Sinan has the correct answer--the OP is using my on every line.

Comment: I am entering proper username and password, so there should be no reason for database connection to fail. What other things could cause Database Connection ?

Comment: Since he has 'RaiseError'=>1, wouldn't his program die if it failed to connect?

Answer (score 1):

As daotoad said, your `DBI->connect` call is failing. Check your connection settings, see if you can connect to the database from the command line, etc. In your Perl script, always check the return value of `DBI->connect()` to see if the connection was successful.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=SPM;host=IP Address",...)
          or die sprintf( 'connect() failed. Error: %s', DBI->errstr);

my $dbh->do(q{
   INSERT INTO payment_methods(name, description)VALUES(CASH, DOLLAR)
});
...
```

Comment: I am able to connect to database from command line but when i try to do so from Perl Script it is giving me above mentioned error message.

Comment: @Sinan - thanks, my DBI is rusty and I forgot about `DBI->errstr`

Comment: @Ingel: did you mean `"...;host=IP address"` or should it be `"...:host=IP address"` ?